# NVL function in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle and I want to replace null values with 0 but it does not work. This is my query:

```
with pivot_data as (
  select (NVL(d.annulation,0)) as annulation ,
    d.id_cc1_annulation as nature ,
    t.mois as mois
  from datamart_cnss d , ref_temps t 
  where t.id_temps = d.id_temps
)
select * from pivot_data
PIVOT ( sum(annulation)
        for nature in (2 as debit ,1 as redit) 
) 
order by mois asc;
```

Comment: on the face of it your use of NVL looks correct, it would be useful if you could provide INSERT statements for the data in the annulation table. If i had to guess at this point i would say that the d.annulation column is not actually NULL.

Comment: Please show sample data, current output, and expected output. You probably want to handle nulls in the pivot, not (just) in the base query?

Answer (score 0):

I guess (because of missing example), your idea is to show no nulls in the result after pivoting. If so, your query (I guess) doesn't always return both `nature` values 1 and 2.

The `NVL` operator in this case works fine, but you put it in a wrong place. This is the place which generates your `NULL` because of no rows found for the given criteria:

```
PIVOT ( sum(annulation)
```

If you enhance **this** `sum` result with the love of `NVL` - I am pretty sure it will work as you expect.